# Stop alexa to gain the visitor stats

Tags: statistics, limit, nofollow, alexa-internet

Is there a way I stop alexa to gain the visitors stats, I don't want that every one search my domain in alexa and get information about the overal users stats or get the information that on which country are users viewing my site the most or other stats about them.
For example when we do not want the crawlers to get to some of our pages and limit the indexing on them, we use `nofollow` as meta tag or on `rel` attribute of links, 
But what can we do for alexa robots? is there a way to limit alexa too?

Answer (score 0):

Alexa gets its information from browser toolbars that you install on purpose or as part of a bundle with some software. For some browsers it modifies User Agent so you can check if user is reporting to Alexa using

```
<?php if (preg_match('/(Alexa)/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {echo 'This is Alexa Reporter :)';) ?>
```

But you cannot prevent getting information by Alexa. Even if you redirect all these people somewhere Alexa will still know referring domains, search keywords, etc.

Here is an article that provides more information about Alexa Rank - http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm